# Converting character variabls to numeric in SAS

Tags: sas

I am creating a numeric version of a character variable in SAS.
I am using the best32. numeric format along with an input statement, as I do not want to lose any data.

Below is an example that in which SAS is dropping data and I am unclear as to why.

```
   DATA trial;
X='1264263.336532';
Y=INPUT(X,BEST32.);
PUT Y;
RUN;
```

Y is only 1264263.3365 and not X.  I am unsure why this is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SAS is displaying the number in the default BEST12. format.
Try PUT Y best32.; instead

Comment: That did it.  I also noticed that SAS is storing the wrong value for Y in the data set itself, or is it just displaying the best12. version?  I did a format y best32. and y displays exactly as x in the data set when I do that.  Does the best12. version of y affect mathematical calculations.  Say if i make z=x as best32. and include a format z best32. and compare it to y without the format statement.

Comment: The INPUT function applies an informat, so unless you specify a format separately then the number will be displayed using the default best12.

Comment: So does that mean that z and y can be equal, even though they are both do not show the same displayed value?  I am just trying to understand if a numbers format has an affect on mathematical calculations.

Comment: Yes and no.  Numeric format will not affect regular calculations (ie, math).  However, if you are classifying *by* a numeric variable, and it has a format, all values with the same formatted value will be grouped together - like if you had Age, and had an Age format that showed '18-25' '26-35' etc.

Comment: SAS always stored numbers as floating point. Formats are for display purpose only and do not affect the underlying numeric value.