# Remove Dollar signs from SAS Column

Tags: sas, reformatting

I have an SAS dataset that has $'s in with some of the columns. So instead of reading 67,349 it reads $67,349. How do I remove all the $'s from all the columns and have SAS recognize them as numbers?

There are only a few columns with the dollar signs so I can do each column one at a time. I am using the free university edition of SAS.

Comment: You already have a SAS dataset?  Or are you creating a SAS dataset from a source file?

Comment: I have an existing data set in that dataset a couple of the columns include dollar signs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to remove the $ and still have a character variable then use the `compress()` function.

```
data want;
  set have;
  myvar = compress(myvar,'$');
run;
```

If you want to convert the character string to a new numeric variable then see this existing question. The `COMMA.` informat will automatically ignore the `$` and `,` characters in the string. [Converting character variabls to numeric in SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19984573/converting-character-variabls-to-numeric-in-sas)

Answer (score 5):

Why not just use the `dollar.` informat?

```
data want ;
  incol ="$62,123" ;
  outcol = input(incol,dollar10.) ;
run ;
```

Answer (score 2):

I would remove the $ and , values from the string variable.  Then use the input function to convert to a number.

```
data test;
format incol $12.;

incol = "$62,123";
incol = compress(translate(incol,"","$,"));
outcol = input(incol,best.);
output;

incol = "62,123.3";
incol = compress(translate(incol,"","$,"));
outcol = input(incol,best.);
output;
run;
```

`TRANSLATE()` replaces $ and , with whitespace.  `COMPRESS()` removes all whitespace.  `INPUT()` converts a string into a number.

Of course you can put all that in 1 call, but I broke it out here to make it easier to follow.

Comment: Where do I use the name of my column? in this case "HOME_VAL". Do I replace the "$62,123"?

Comment: `incol` and `outcol` are just place holders.  Replace `incol` with your column and `outcol` with what you want to call the new column. You can always drop the old column and rename the new one back to the original name if need be.

Comment: This was adding rows to the data set